# how to know whether modal boxes (alert, prompt, confirm...) have been disabled in javascript?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I have a private web based app where sometimes I genuinely ask to the users what they want to do in given situations. To do so, I'm using the `confirm` function of javascript.

As any other modal box, after a few popups the user has the choice to disable them by simply clicking the little box as showed below:

[image]

The problem is that, if they clicked it once, they never see other messages and responses to `confirm` are assumed `0`, which is confusing because basically it means that all the actions requiring their confirmation are cancelled with no warning! Refreshing the page does not help, they have to close it and reopen it for it to work again.

Can I detect when they checked that little box?

Comment: Do you have to use an `alert` or `confirm`? Ideally you would just use an in-page modal system? Like http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Why don't you use CSS dialogs instead of `confirm()`?

Comment: I don't want to prevent it, I want to know when the user clicked the box

Comment: @barmar and loganfsmyth, I like to use native features

Comment: CSS is a native feature. If you want control over the user experience, use HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

Comment: Even though dressing these features up seems superfluous, pretty things are perceived to work better.

Comment: @fbynite I think they are totally different. The CSS option is only modal visually. While the popup is showing, the execution of javascript is not stopped. Also, how would you replicate exactly the behaviour of the confirm box? I didn't try jquery but I doubt they stop the execution of the page until you press ok or cancel.

Comment: @Sebas They are totally different, but it is precisely the JS execution stopping that causes Chrome to implement the  "Prevent the page ..." option. `alert`/`confirm` not only show a popup, but they take focus from other tabs and make it impossible to interact with the page, meaning they are very likely to be a nuisance to users.

Comment: @loganfsmyth the concept of modal dialog exists since premices of user interface. It is not a nuisance unless you abuse of it. I personnally don't see any problem in it, I just want to *know* when it has been disabled by the user...

Comment: A CSS modal isn't appropriate in all cases. For example, I need to prompt for deletion confirmation during a plugin's event callback. `confirm` allows me to do that, but trying to replicate the behavior with a CSS modal, which can't stop the flow of execution and be self-contained in that callback, would require rewriting a lot of code and making a mess of things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When that box is checked, the dialog "closes" immediately. You could check to see if the box closes unusually fast:

```
function dialog(message, success, failure) {
    var open_time = new Date();
    var result = alert(message);
    var close_time = new Date();

    if (close_time - open_time < 10) {
        failure();
    } else {
        success(result);
    }
}

dialog('Hello', function(result) {
    // The dialog probably was closed by the user
}, function() {
    // The dialog was closed really fast.
    // Either the user was typing while it popped up or the browser didn't
    //  display it in the first place
});
```

Although just using CSS and HTML to create modal dialogs would probably be much easier and more consistent across browsers and platforms. I personally don't like Chrome's approach.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tS9G6/4/**

I looked a little bit through Chromium's source and that property isn't stored anywhere, so there doesn't seem to be some Chromium-specific property that you can look at.

Comment: But is there any way to know for sure?

Comment: @NisargShah: no

Answer (score 3):

You can't do anything about it. It's a browser feature.

You can check for the timing -

[How to Detect "prevent this page from creating additional dialogs"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571015/how-to-detect-prevent-this-page-from-creating-additional-dialogs)

This suggests doing the following :

```
function myConfirm(message){
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var result = confirm(message);
    var dt = new Date().getTime() - start;
    // dt < 50ms means probable computer
    // the quickest I could get while expecting the popup was 100ms
    // slowest I got from computer suppression was 20ms
    for(var i=0; i < 10 && !result && dt < 50; i++){
        start = new Date().getTime();
        result = confirm(message);
        dt = new Date().getTime() - start;
    }
    if(dt < 50)
       return true;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to do anything against it

Comment: I updated my response with another's suggestion - I think it makes sense here. Sorry for the confusion.