# Check if alert is disabled

Tags: javascript

In chrome there is a way to disable alerts by selecting "prevent this page from creating additional dialogs".

Is there a way to check via javascript if the user has disabled the alerts ?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672490/how-to-know-whether-modal-boxes-alert-prompt-confirm-have-been-disabled-i

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible to do in any clean way as it's a browser feature, and if the browser doesn't let you know then you can't know.

Answer (score 11):

try this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/c6upcLns/)

```
function checkIfAlertDisabled()
{
   var startTime = new Date().getTime();
   alert("asdasdasdasdasdasd");
   var endTime = new Date().getTime();

   return ( endTime - startTime ) < 50; 
}

console.log( checkIfAlertDisabled() );
```

I think **50** is a safe number since usually it won't take more than 1 millisecond to process a non-working alert. Also, there is very unlikely that someone will be able to process a working-alert within 50 milliseconds.

Comment: it worked but it show the alert asdasdasdasdasdasd when I close the alert.

Comment: @xRobot didn't get you. Are you saying that it showed alert again after you disabled the alert?

Comment: No, I am using this: if((confirm("Do you want to STOP ?"))||(checkIfAlertDisabled())) { So when the alerts are not disabled and appear the confirm dialog and then I press Cancel, then appear the asdasdasdasdasdasd alert.

Comment: @xRobot it is not happening for me in chrome. Which browser are you testing on?