# 'Confirm' popup default value when blocked by browser

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to provide a default value for a basic javascript 'confirm' popup if the user has chosen to block popups in their browser (such as Edge)?

I'm looking to add a very simple confirm dialog on a web application to confirm an element is to be deleted.

Right now, I just have this line before the delete action :

```
if (!confirm("Delete this element?")) { return; }

// Code to delete the element here
```

Ideally, if the user chooses to block popups on their browser, the confirm popup should simply delete without further requests.

Comment: I think `alert()`, `prompt()` and `confirm()` being pretty annoying and old-fashionned. I would use kind of some [bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

Comment: No, that is not possible. I suggest you create your own `dialog` element with *Yes* and *No* buttons and make it appear whenever a user tries to delete anything.

Comment: Your options are either to implement your own "confirm" popup, or follow [this (rather hacky) work-around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20672625/1612146)

Comment: Does confirm evaluate as false, null, or undefined if it is blocked by the browser?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm found my own answer, it returns as false. I agree with the other posters, make some sort of modal confirm, or go with the hacky way.

Comment: @CalIrvine it returns false, the same value as clicking cancel on the popup.